# page not showing for developing an app

Tags: facebook, admin

I am admin. of 4 pages, when I go to develop an app, it will only show 2 of those pages as options ?  The one I need doesn't show.   They are all the same type of page.  How do I get the needed page to show?

Answer (score 0):

The pages are not supposed to appear on the developer menu so I'm wondering where exactly don't these 2 pages show up?
Do you mean they don't show up when you want to add an app to them, as a tab?
They don't show up on your Insights menu, to see their stats?

Please, elaborate your question